# Grand Quattro boot loop and can't go to recovery mode

Tags: root-access, samsung, odin

Let's keep this simple...

- I root my phone using Kingo ROOT and now can't boot.
- This... https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v7fbrlep05oc3y/WP_20150308_15_34_19_Pro.mp4?dl=0
- Note that my phone is grand quattro and not win
- Can't go to recovery mode but can access download mode.
- I have Odin.

What should I do? Format or something? :/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you made a nandroid backup... if you are able to get into download mode you should be fine. Put the device in download mode. Have the device connected to the pc. Open odin. Make sure that odin recognizes the device. There should be numbers in the first small box in odin above the ID:COM. Select your pda file by clicking pda in odin. Select the tar.md5 file that you should have downloaded. If you do not have this file you can get it by searching for a thread for rooting your phone. Once your device has been recognized and you have the md5 file selected, click start. The overall process should take 10-15 seconds. Once the process has been completed the phone should restart. You can now disconnect the phone. You should now be root. 
*note* this will trip the Knox counter so you may not be able to claim warranty.
Now download clockworkmod recovery md5 file for your phone. Now do the previous steps up to where you select the md5 file. So when you click pda this time select the clockworkmod recovery file you just downloaded. Now you can do this next part two ways:

1. If you are able to boot your phone you can leave auto reboot checked in odin and then hit start.

Or:

2. You can uncheck autoreboot so that your phone stays powered off after you click start. Now you should be able to boot into recovery and recover your nandroid backup.

This anwser is based on not knowing if you are still able to boot into your phone or not. If this anwser does not fix your problem please post some clarification and I will try to adjust my anwser. Hope this helps